# Crystal Report and alternatives

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am a newbie in Crystal Reports, I have few questions regarding it:

1) Is Crystal Reports part of .NET Framework?

2) Is there a specific version of Crystal Report that is compatible with specific version of .NET Framework / Visual Studio ?

3) Can we use Crystal Reports with other platforms as well, like Java, etc ?

4) What are the alternatives available for reporting and how does Crystal Report compare with them ?

Comment: Type your question in Google...

Comment: Sir my question is not exactly what is crystal reports, but the points which are there below... I think Google is always there, but I post question here to get current advice from the professionals who are working.

Comment: That is a quite selfish way of thinking, Brij. Please do search before asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did run a search for Is Crystal Reports part of .NET Framework, didn't get much, other than the thing that it is no longer bundled with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

1. It was once a part of Visual Studio but it no longer is.
2. It is no longer bundled; instead Microsoft has SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)
3. Yes, there are even plugins for Eclipse.
4. Around my office it seems that SSRS is heavily preferred. [Jasper](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) seems to be a popular open source alternative.

Comment: So is SSRS better than Crystal Reports ? I have not idea of SSRS. Can it be used with .NET Applications just like Cyrstal Reports?